# ¿se puede llenar un Array con Prompt?

Tags: javascript, web

Una consulta, suponiendo que tengo el siguiente código:

```
    function palabras(...REST){
    console.log("Palabras: ", REST);
    }
    palabras("uno", "dos", "tres");
```

posiblemente tendré una salida en donde el array `REST` este así:

```
REST[o]: uno
REST[1]: dos
REST[2]: tres
```

mi duda es, ¿Hay alguna forma de llenar un array(como este del ejemplo) a través de un prompt sin recurrir a un bucle?
intente con algo como:

```
function palabras(...REST){
console.log("Palabras: ", REST);
}
palabras(prompt());
```

Entrada del prompt: "uno", "dos", "tres"
pero el array me lo tomaba como si fuera un solo "valor", o sea, algo como:

```
REST[o]: ""uno", "dos", "tres""
```

de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es ingresar múltiples elementos dentro del `prompt` y este te los agregue dentro de un array, si es así entonces puedes hacerlo por medio de un `split`, te muestro un ejemplo donde tienes que separar cada elemento por un espacio en blanco, en caso de que desees que cada elemento se separe por medio de una coma (,) entonces colócala dentro del `split`(ejemplo: `let items = action.split(',');`) :

```js
let action = prompt();
let items = action.split(' ');

console.log(items);
```

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Era justo lo que necesitaba, gracias!

Comment: Que bueno que te ha sido de ayuda, suerte :D

Answer (score 1):

Reordenando el codigo de la pregunta mas lo agregado por @Blas tenemos:

```js
const muestraPalabras= function palabras(...REST){
console.log("Palabras: ", REST);
}

const formatoArray= function convierteArray(entrada)
{
 return  entrada.split(' ');

}

 function myFunction() {
  var entrada = prompt("introduzca palabras separadas por espacio");
  if (entrada != null) {
     var itemsEntrada= formatoArray(entrada);
   
   if(Array.isArray(itemsEntrada))
     {
       muestraPalabras(itemsEntrada);  
     }
      
      
   
  }
  }
```

```html
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Introduzca arreglo</button>


//Quitas los ... despues de rest si lo consideras necesario
```

Comment: Es una buena forma de verlo, Gracias!